# Cannot build release version of KMM app in iOS

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to build a release build for my KMM app on iOS. The progress fails with message
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find 'libCryptoKitWrapper.a' binary in neither of [CryptoKitWrapper/build/Release-iphoneos]`
The exception traces to the Swift library I'm using. For it to work on kotlin I'm using this [method](https://medium.com/kodein-koders/create-a-kotlin-multiplatform-library-with-swift-1a818b2dc1b0). Surprisingly the file in question can be found in the listed directory. What might be the problem here? Related cinterop task:

```
iosTarget("ios") {
    val platform = when (preset?.name) {
        "iosX64" -> "iphonesimulator"
        "iosArm64" -> "iphoneos"
        else -> error("Unsupported target $name")
    }
    compilations.getByName("main") {
        cinterops.create("CryptoKitWrapper") {
            val interopTask = tasks[interopProcessingTaskName]
            interopTask.dependsOn(":CryptoKitWrapper:build${platform.capitalize()}")
            includeDirs.headerFilterOnly("$rootDir/CryptoKitWrapper/build/Release-$platform/include")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a sample project demonstrating the issue ?

Comment: Made it [here](https://github.com/MJegorovas/SwiftLibSample). Note that in this building release works, but building archive to upload to AppStore sitll shows the problem.

Comment: @SalomonBRYS any luck reproducing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that the Gradle interprets locations set with `libraryPaths` as a relative path, deriving it from current OS directory. To observe this, try executing `./gradlew :shared:cinteropCryptoKitWrapperIos --info` from `SwiftLibSample` dir, and `../gradlew cinteropCryptoKitWrapperIos --info` from `SwiftLibSample/shared`. The first one should work correctly.

To workaround the problem, one can do the following. Instead of hard-coding path to the `.def` file, set this parameter inside the `cinterops{...}` block. I tried this one, inspired by the @SalomonBRYS' answer at https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/2314

```
cinterops.create("CryptoKitWrapper") {
                ...
                extraOpts("-libraryPath", "$rootDir/CryptoKitWrapper/build/Release-$platform")
                ...
```

If you would like to receive updates on this problem, please follow this issue at the official Kotlin issue tracker [KT-48082](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-48082)

###### EDIT: The following does not directly relate to the original question, I just want to summarize my tips from the comment section below.

To enable the bitcode used in the project layout as in https://github.com/MJegorovas/SwiftLibSample, one should:

1. Make the static library contain the Bitcode. In this case, `"BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode"` option should be across `xcodebuild` arguments.
2. Make the cinterop tool link the library with the bitcode. Add `-lto-embed-bitcode` linker option to the `.def` file.

Comment: That solved one problem - after trying to archive again I get error `Bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/Users/developer/AndroidStudioProjects/SwiftLibSample/shared/build/cocoapods/framework/shared.framework/shared(result.o)' was built without full bitcode. All object files and libraries for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build file '/Users/developer/AndroidStudioProjects/SwiftLibSample/shared/build/cocoapods/framework/shared.framework/shared' for architecture arm64`. This can be fixed by setting "Enable Bitcode" in build to false.Is this good solution?

Comment: Hmm. I've played with your test project a bit more, and adding this to your def file `linkerOpts = -L/usr/lib/swift -lto-embed-bitcode` helped. Could you please give it a try?

Comment: Sadly, this does not solve the problem - same error again. Maybe you added something more? I updated my sample with your suggestions, so you could take a look - maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Right now I see two differencies(except the fact I changed  the Development team ofc). I removed libraryPaths lines from CryptoKitWrapper.def to make sure the tool will use option send from build.gradle.kts. Also, I changed [this](https://github.com/MJegorovas/SwiftLibSample/blob/4e45c1ddb4894094798f8a5496c468e9b2e5d9bc/SwiftLibSample/shared/build.gradle.kts#L31) to be just `includeDirs`.

Comment: You mean like [this](https://github.com/MJegorovas/SwiftLibSample/commit/332fa20475c201b69473f1b35e59b44e65d5ebe9)? Still getting same error. Not related question - if those 2 lines from build.gradle are commented out after cleaning project and building it again I get errors because as I understand then `:CryptoKitWrapper:build...` task is not being executed. Are you executing it separately or some other way?

Comment: No, I meant `includeDirs(` instead of `includeDirs.headerFilterOnly(`

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your previous comment. Applied the fix, but same error shows up.

Comment: I checked once again, and found a mistake in my recommendations. I've also tried to add this to the `CryptoKitWrapper/build.gradle.kts`: at the xcodebuild call you should also add this line`"xcodebuild",
            "BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode",
           "-project", "CryptoKitWrapper.xcodeproj",`. After that, execute `./gradlew clean` and try running the `Archive` from the Xcode.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much for your time! Please continue working on improving the ecosystem!